# Function not able to access observableArray in knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I keep getting this error when I try to update an observableArray:
'Unable to get property 'removeAll' of undefined or null reference'

Here is my code:

```
var agilityFirmViewModel = {
    test: ko.computed(function () {
        return Pairs[0].Pairs;
    }),

    currentLocation: ko.observableArray(Pairs[0].Pairs[0].Location);

//function to update values in currentLocation
 ChangeLocation: function (practiceGroup) {
        if (practiceGroup === undefined) {
            practiceGroup = '(All Practice Groups)';
        }
        for (var i = 0; i <= Pairs[0].Pairs.length; i++) {
            if (practiceGroup.Department === Pairs[0].Pairs[i].Department) {
                this.currentLocation.removeAll();
                this.currentLocation.push(practiceGroup.Location[i]);
                return root.currentLocation;
            }
        }
    },
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(agilityFirmViewModel);
});
```

Assuming that it goes through the if statement inside the for loop everytime,
whenever it gets to

```
this.currentLocation.removeAll();
```

I get the error above saying that currentLocation is undefined. I know that currentLocation has data in it, so would could be causing this issue. It's probably something simple, but I can't seem to figure it out. Thank you.

Where i call ChangeLocation():

```
       <li class="nav-sidebar-GreenMenu">
                    <a href="javascript:;" class="draggable-panel" draggable="true">
                        <i id="CategoryIcon" class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>
                        <span class="sidebarTabName"><b>Practice Group</b></span><br />
                        <!--For some reason, changing the margin-left below will change the width of the entire sidebar-->
                        <span id="CurrentItem_TPG" class="currentItem" @*style="margin-left:64px;"*@>(All Practice Groups)</span>
                        <span id="DefaultItem_TPG" style="display:none;">(All Practice Groups)</span>
                        <i class="fa fa-chevron-left pull-right hidden-xs" data-bind=""></i>
                        <span class="arrow open" style="margin-top:-30px;"></span>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu">            
                        <!--ko foreach: test()-->
                            <li>  
                                <a href="#" data-bind="text: $data.Department, value: $data.Department, click: $root.ChangeLocation.bind($data.Department)" class="active"></a>
                            </li>
                        <!-- /ko -->
                    </ul>
                </li>
```

Comment: Please post your code where you call `ChangeLocation`! If it used in a click binding then the relevant part of your HTML.

Comment: @nemesv I posted that part of the code. Thanks

Comment: Do you expect `$data.Department` to have a `currentLocation` property?

Comment: $data.Department is part of an object that comes back that is used to get the locations for that department. Based on what department is selected, the correct locations will come back for it.

Comment: @NickRoberto Then see my answer. You're using `bind` incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the way you're using [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind). The actual signature for `bind` is:

> fun.bind(thisArg[, arg1[, arg2[, ...]]])

Meaning, the first argument determines what `this` means in the function and the rest sets the arguments to use when it's called. Instead, try changing your click handler to this:

```
$parent.ChangeLocation.bind($parent, $data);
```

This ensures that `ChangeLocation` is called with `$parent === this` and `$data === practiceGroup`

Comment: So does it need to be in exactly as you have it written, or would I write it as:
$parent.ChangeLocation.bind($parent, $data.Department);

I got the same error message when I tried it the way you mentioned. Thanks

Comment: @NickRoberto Based on your function, I believe it should be exactly as I've written it unless `$data.Department` has a `Department` property (`$data.Department.Department`).